# How to document overloaded methods with the same XML comments?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I know there are questions like this, but they're old. So I'm creating a new one.

At the moment when there are 3 overloaded methods I have to do this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Description that described summary of an overloaded method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName">Description that describes filename parameter</param>
/// <param name="options">Description that describes options parameter</param>
/// <returns>Description of what method returns</returns>
public bool ReadFrom(string fileName, ReaderOptions options = null) {
    return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Description that described summary of an overloaded method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stream">Description that describes stream parameter</param>
/// <param name="options">Description that describes options parameter</param>
/// <returns>Description of what method returns</returns>
public bool ReadFrom(Stream stream, ReaderOptions options = null) {
    return false;
}

/// <summary>
/// Description that described summary of an overloaded method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rawData">Description that describes rawData parameter</param>
/// <param name="options">Description that describes options parameter</param>
/// <returns>Description of what method returns</returns>
public bool ReadFrom(byte[] rawData, ReaderOptions options = null) {
    return false;
}
```

And I would like to have something like this:

```
#region overloadedReadFromMethods
/// <summary>
/// Description that described summary of an overloaded method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName">Description that describes filename parameter</param>
/// <param name="options">Description that describes options parameter</param>
/// <returns>Description of what method returns</returns>
public bool ReadFrom(string fileName, ReaderOptions options = null) {
    return false;
}

/// <param name="stream">Description that describes stream parameter</param>
public bool ReadFrom(Stream stream, ReaderOptions options = null) {
    return false;
}

/// <param name="rawData">Description that describes rawData parameter</param>
/// <returns>Even considering that returns tag is present on the first overloaded method,
/// this overloaded method shows this specific description.
/// </returns>
public bool ReadFrom(byte[] rawData, ReaderOptions options = null) {
    return false;
}
#endregion overloadedReadFromMethods
```

So the first overloaded method describes default description and then methods below can override it with their own descriptions. I want it to show in Visual Studio's IntelliSense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR - It's not possible

Long story short, as was the case in the past, you still cannot re-use comments this way.

### [Some interesting ideas here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667784/documenting-overloaded-methods-with-the-same-xml-comments)

1. Create one function with optional parameters. While this would mitigate the problem, I find that optional parameters are sometimes incovenient themselves as they overcomplicate the logic inside and make unit testing very difficult. Overaloading in your case make sense, so this solution does not apply.
2. Use the `<overloads>` comment. I can't see it in the official documentation though
3. Use the `<see>` and `<seealso>` xml tag to use reference

### Use the `<include>` tag

This is still not a solution but it allows you to have separate xml documents and handle overall. [include documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/include)

Comment: Thanks. I read about <overloads>, <see> and <seealso> but couldn't make it work. How do I use these? Will these help me to avoid duplication in any way? Maybe at least I don't have to copy-paste descriptions themselves(text in-between tags).

Comment: You won't make much out of it.  Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/see for see usage. It will just show an make discoverable the including type.

Comment: The overloads does not see to be in the official documentation, so I don't expect any studio to change anything, other than telling the user to check the other overload for comments.

Comment: About 1. Yes, that's I'm trying to avoid: complex logic in super methods. So I don't have to do public bool ReadFrom(string fileName ="", Stream stream = null, byte[] rawData = null, ReaderOptions options = null).

Comment: You are pretty much out of luck... I would use the include tag only for packaged libraries, truth be told...

Comment: In this question you linked in your answer, @Kache suggested using <overloads>. There is no documentation and I don't understand how to use it. I tried to put <overloads> before first /// <summary> and to put <overloads> at the end after the last curly bracket, and it doesn't work.

Comment: It's just a custom tag to indicate that there's an overload with comments. Nothing special to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the extra work to document each method is necessary because they all have different signatures. Methods have different `<param></param>`

[InheritDoc](https://www.inheritdoc.io/) is a package that can be used to inherit xml docs.

Comment: Thanks. Installing extra package isn't a problem for me. I'm documenting it for other people to use in the future(Github repository), and for myself when I forget. And they will probably not have that on their PCs. I guess it will work nicely for a compiled module, but for contributors without InheritDoc it will still not show descriptions for overloads, right?